# Insert data into foreign table using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id int auto_increment,
  name varchar(10),
  CONSTRAINT pk_id primary key(id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  id_fk int,
  stuff varchar(30),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id_fk) REFERENCES table1(id) 
)
```

I want to insert a record in both of these tables. Basically, I've id, name & stuff as data. How do I insert them into both tables using Spring JDBC?

I'm inserting into tables as shown below:

```
    SimpleJdbcInsert insert1 = new SimpleJdbcInsert(this.getDataSource())
        .withTableName("table1")
        .usingColumns("name");

    Map<String, Object> parameters1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters1.put("name", myObj1.getStuff());
    insert.execute(parameters1);
```

While inserting into table2, how do I get the id value from table1?

```
    SimpleJdbcInsert insert2 = new SimpleJdbcInsert(this.getDataSource())
        .withTableName("table2")
        .usingColumns("stuff");

    Map<String, Object> parameters2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters2.put("stuff", myObj2.getStuff());
    insert.execute(parameters2);
```

Also, how do I maintain transaction?

Also, how do I fetch data for a given name?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this simple example, all methods in class Test will be transactional, read Spring Framework docs for more

```
@Transactional
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    DataSource ds;

    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("c1", "test");
        SimpleJdbcInsert insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(ds).withTableName("t1").usingColumns("c1")
                .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
        long id = insert.executeAndReturnKey(params).longValue();

    params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("stuff", "stuff");
    params.put("id_fk", id);
    SimpleJdbcInsert insert2 = new SimpleJdbcInsert(ds).withTableName(
            "table2").usingColumns("stuff", "id_fk");
    insert2.execute(params);

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate tmpl = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
        params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("id", id);
        String c1 = tmpl.queryForObject("select c1 from t1 where id = :id", params, String.class);
    }
```

context

```
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&amp;password=root" />
</bean>

<bean class="Test" />
```

Comment: Thanks for sample code. I can see that you're inserting into table t1 but what about insertion into table t2 using the id generated from table t1??

Comment: thanks...one more question: do I need to add transactionManager bean with datasource as property? Who will invoke transactionManager?

Comment: Yes, you need to be transactional since you have 2 inserts in 1 method. tx:annotation-driven + @Transactional + transactionManager makes Spring understand that test1() must be 1 transaction